# Restoring webapps after trashing them in unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, webapps

To remove a webapp for a website I took his icon from the unity launcher to the trash icon.
Now I want to restore the same webapp: how should I do it?

Note:

```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-webapps-XXX
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you removed the webapps from unity launcher. Those webapps launchers will be stored in `~/.local/share/applications` folder.

Open `~/.local/share/applications` folder. Drag and drop the `.desktop` files to unity launcher will bring back the webapps.

Sample Desktop entry for twitter:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Twitter
Type=Application
Icon=Twitter-twitter.com
MimeType=
Actions=S0;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6;S7;S8;S9;S10;
Exec=unity-webapps-runner -n 'aBCdegFG=' -d 'twitter.com' %u
```

Hope this helps.